# MySQL Nested Query returning 'Unknown column' even though column exists

Tags: mysql

Im trying to do a very simple nested query

```
SELECT group FROM customer_table WHERE customer_table.customer_number=other_table.cust_num
```

But the query is returning

'#1054 - Unknown column 'other_table.cust_num' in 'where clause'

Both the table and column definitely do exist and are named correctly in the query.  Am I doing something obviously stupid ?  Any help would be very much appreciated as I think Im going crazy.

Comment: Was the answers below helpful? If yes, you can upvote and mark as correct to make them more useful for other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write other_table in the query, it is not known to the compiler. Thats why you get the undefined error.
 To select or compare the data from two tables we use **JOINS**.
Joins are of different types- **Inner, cross**,etc.
 The correct query would be

```
    SELECT customer_table.group 
    FROM customer_table 
    INNER JOIN other_table 
    ON customer_table.customer_number = other_table.cust_num;
```

Join combines the two table according to the condition specified by **ON** clause.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is known as a join.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT customer_table.group 
FROM customer_table 
INNER JOIN other_table ON customer_table.customer_number = other_table.cust_num;
```

You are getting the error because you specified a table/column condition in the `WHERE` clause that wasn't a part of the query